# write playbook for create Azure instances

Tags: ansible

I'm working Ansible for create Azure instances using playbook, i got below error can anybody solve this.

```
 [WARNING]: Found both group and host with same name: localhost

[DEPRECATION WARNING]: azure is kept for backwards compatibility but usage is discouraged. The module documentation details page may explain more about this
 rationale.. This feature will be removed in a future release. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.

PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [create VM] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (azure) module: Subscription_ID Supported parameters include: auto_updates,enable_winrm,endpoints,hostname,image,location,management_cert_path,name,os_type,password,role_size,ssh_cert_path,state,storage_account,subscription_id,user,virtual_network_name,wait,wait_timeout,wait_timeout_redirects"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/int.retry

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an error message for you:

> Unsupported parameters for (azure) module: **Subscription_ID**

Please check the docs for [azure](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/azure_module.html) module and [azure guide](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/guide_azure.html).

If you want to supply credentials via env variables, you may wan to try:

```
- azure:
    name: my-virtual-machine
    role_size: Small
    image: b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu_DAILY_BUILD-precise-12_04_3-LTS-amd64-server-20131205-en-us-30GB
    ...  
  environment:
    AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: xxxxx
```

But you should follow azure guide and setup credentials outside your playbook.